# Contextual validations in ActiveRecord using with_options and an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Moving from Datamapper to ActiveRecord recently and one cool feature that we were using is contextual validations and using with_options that could pass an array as below:

```
with_options when: [:started, :completed] do |v|
  v.validates_with_method :has_data, method: :check_data_started?
end
```

Which would then fire all validations within the block if `.valid?(:started)` or `.valid?(:completed)` were called.

Is there a way to do this with Active Record, I tried:

```
with_options on: [:started, :completed] do |v|
  v.validate :check_data_started?
end
```

Which looks blows up with an error is saying I can't pass an array within my with_options call, as it's only expecting one context:

`/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...ue && (validation_context == :[:started, :complet...`

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If anyone else runs into this problem, please see below for a solution:

```
with_options if: -> {[:started, :completed].include?(validation_context)} do |v|
  v.validates_with_method :has_data, method: :check_data_started?
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to refactor those conditions inside the lambda into a method and call it? I put my method in there but it just ignores it